# how to make line-break tag work in html when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem where I want a line break 
 tag added dynamically in the code never works after the first tag which is anchor 
I want every link added dynamically should go on new line

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function addAnchorNode(){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://Google.co.uk');
    link.innerHTML = "Hello, Google!";

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendchild(document.createElement('br')); //Never Works
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="addAnchorNode()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.body.appendchild(document.createElement('br'));` says that there is no method `appendchild`. It should be `appendChild`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to have something after your BR, and no typo ("appendChild", not "appendchild").

This works :

```
function addAnchorNode(){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://Google.co.uk');
    link.innerHTML = "Hello, Google!";

    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rsNqt/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, whereas I did the same as you have suggested while playing with code and I did even achieve the desired results that every new link was going onto new line. Tell me that why can't we place this     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
after anchor tag document.body.appendChild(link);
 Why we have to do it before anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct and issue is with "appendChild", Please find the working code below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function addAnchorNode(){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://Google.co.uk');
    link.innerHTML = "Hello, Google!";

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    //document.body.appendchild(document.createElement('br')); //Never Works
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="addAnchorNode()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```